# Поиск по сайту c MySQL

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript, mysql

Хочу сделать поиск без перезагрузки с помощью `ajax` на `jQuery`, но выдает ошибку. Хотя без `ajax` все работает отлично...

---

Вот скрипт `jQuery`

```
//Форма поиска
$('#search-result #search button').live('click', function () {
    $('#loader').show();
    var zapros = $('#search-result #search input').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "include/search_result.php",
        data: ({
            searchs: zapros
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
            $('#loader').hide();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

---

Вот обработчик

```
if (isset($_POST['searchs'])) {
    $searchs = mysql_escape_string(strip_tags(trim($_POST['searchs'])));
    
    
    
    $errors = array();
    if (empty($searchs)) {
        $errors[] = 'Введите поисковой запрос!';
    } else if (strlen(utf8_decode($searchs)) < 3) {
        $errors[] = 'Запрос должен быть более 3 символов!';
    }
    if (empty($errors)) {
        //Обработка запроса
        
        $returned_results = array();
        $where            = "";
        
        $searchs      = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $searchs);
        $total_search = count($searchs);
        
        foreach ($searchs as $key => $search) {
            $where .= "text LIKE '%$search%'";
            
            if ($key != ($total_search - 1)) {
                $where .= " OR ";
            }
        }
        
        $results_searchs = "SELECT id,category,title,date,view,description,total_value,miniatura,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE comments.lesson = lessons.id) AS com FROM lessons WHERE $where";
        $results_searchs = mysql_query($results_searchs);
        if (mysql_num_rows($results_searchs) > 0) {
            $results_num = mysql_num_rows($results_searchs);
            echo "<p style = 'margin-left: 30px;'>По Вашему запросу <span style = 'color: #F78D1D; font-weight: bold;'>" . $_POST['searchs'] . "</span> найдено <span style = 'color: #F78D1D; font-weight: bold;'>" . $results_num . "</span> совпадений:</p>";
            
            $myrow_searchs = mysql_fetch_array($results_searchs);
            do {
                printf("
                        <div class='lesson'>
                            <img class='mini' src='%s' />
                            <a href = '/lesson.php?category=%s&id=%s'>%s</a>
                            <p>%s</p>
                            <hr>
                            <div class='info'>
                                <span><img src='/img/icon/file_add.png' width='11' height='11' /> Добавлен: %s </span>
                                <span><img src='/img/icon/eye.png' width='11' height='11' /> Просмотров: %s </span>
                                <span><img src='/img/icon/comment.png' width='11' height='11' /> Комментариев: %s </span>
                                <span><img src='/img/icon/rating.png' width='11' height='11' /> Рейтинг: %s </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        ", $myrow_searchs["miniatura"], $myrow_searchs["category"], $myrow_searchs["id"], $myrow_searchs["title"], $myrow_searchs["description"], $myrow_searchs["date"], $myrow_searchs["view"], $myrow_searchs["com"], $myrow_searchs["total_value"]);
            } while ($myrow_searchs = mysql_fetch_array($results_searchs));
            
        } else {
            echo 'По Вашему запросу ' . $_POST['searchs'] . ' ничего не найдено!';
        }
        
    } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo $error, '<br />';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Вы вошли сюда без поискового запроса!';
}
```

---

Вот ошибка

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in Z:\home\vorobyev.ru\www\include\search_result.php on line 40
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in Z:\home\vorobyev.ru\www\include\search_result.php on line 40
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in Z:\home\vorobyev.ru\www\include\search_result.php on line 41

Comment: Уточните: mod_rewrite - используете? Подключение к БД в отдельном файле?

Comment: Ооооооо....вот это точно подмечено....че я и забыл так это подключить бд именно в этом файле...спасибо)))))

Answer (score 0):

У меня код не работал, долго искал и нашел ответ.

Причина простая: она заключается в ключевом слове `LIMIT`.

Результат не выводится, если там очень много совпадений (то есть сотни найденных результатов). В этом случае вам нужно поставить ограничение!

Пример:

```
$post = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, etitle FROM info WHERE title LIKE '%право%' LIMIT 10 ",$db);
```

Тогда все заработает!